# QtDesigner: is it possible to assign top menu item handler?

Tags: qt-designer

In QtDesigner, if i have a pushbutton and want to add a handler for it all i need to do is to right-click this button and select "go to slot" - QtCreator will automatically add a code and connect signal to slot. But top menu items don't have a "go to slot" in right click menu O_O. Is it possible to add handler to top menu item in QtDesigner? Of course i can write a "conect" method manually at constructor, but it's much more easily to do a few clicks in QtDesigner itself -_-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every menu item added corresponding 'command' will be displayed at 'commands' QtDesigner window. Right-click command and select 'go to slot'.